# Problem in build android open source project

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, ubuntu-18.04

[I download android open source project from Here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading)

After downloaded, I used this command to clean UP etc...

```
$ make clobber
```

Then i got this problem

```
build/core/main.mk:42: ********************************************************************************
build/core/main.mk:43: *  You are using version 4.1 of make.
build/core/main.mk:44: *  Android can only be built by version 3.81.
build/core/main.mk:45: *  see http://source.android.com/source/download.html
build/core/main.mk:46: ********************************************************************************
```

I got make 4.1 default from android open source project

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**Excepted solution**

1. How to downgrade 4.1 to 3.81
2. I can't able to install 1.6 JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that hell of dependencies to build AOSP, I live on Arch Linux and working build may fail after a system update.

So now I'm using docker image with all deps preinstalled, without a need to upgrade system there, keeping my desktop Arch Linux independent.

Just some results after googling:

https://github.com/stucki/docker-lineageos (I used this one, but the next one may be a better choice)

https://github.com/jfloff/docker-lineageos

https://hub.docker.com/r/anthodingo/docker-lineageos/

Also you may be interested to know that there's a Linux distro dedicated to AOSP development: http://bbqlinux.org/

Answer (score 0):

As in the requirement say you should use

[image]

Just download it from gnu.org. Here are the requirements for [building AOSP](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements.html)

For your JDK you should run this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

*Don't forget to uninstall everything JDK, Make before you install the new ones.*

Comment: I have installed every thing, But again I'm getting same problem

Comment: I'm not en expert in Linux, but i would say in Windows you still have those old applications installed.

Comment: yeah @Haroun i'll check